# how to select in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Here are two numpy arrays in the same variable. How do I select the last one in the last row of the array? Putting that in a separate variable?

```
      j = [[7.60243100e+06 7.66034500e+06 7.79095700e+06 7.86080000e+06
         7.90957500e+06 7.94365200e+06 8.05480000e+06]

         [9.92760000e+06 9.94780000e+06 9.98700000e+06 1.00683190e+07
            1.01006310e+07 1.01305740e+07 1.01430470e+07]
```

So I would like to put 1.01430470e+07 and 8.05480000e+06 in a new variable in one column

Comment: It looks like you printed a numpy array, and added the `j = ` in front. It's unclear. Those certainly _are not_ 'two numpy arrays in the same variable', it looks like a two-dimensional array of shape (2, 7). Saying 'put 1.01430470e+07 and 8.05480000e+06 in a new variable in one column' does not make much sense either.

Comment: Oh and I forgot to add that this is extremely basic. Did you try anything? Have you read any of the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make slicing operation on your array.

```
>>> a = np.arange(10).reshape(2,5)
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
>>> a[:,-1]
array([4, 9])
```

This simple yet powerful, -1 takes the last data from the array, or you can also reverse the array and take the first values.
For more info refer: [Numpy Quickstart Guide](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 0):

First I'm setting up your problem, so I can test it. I can't read in the numpy printout as data. Please look up [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for future posts.

```
import numpy as np


listj = [[7.60243100e+06, 7.66034500e+06, 7.79095700e+06 ,7.86080000e+06,
         7.90957500e+06, 7.94365200e+06, 8.05480000e+06],

         [9.92760000e+06, 9.94780000e+06, 9.98700000e+06, 1.00683190e+07,
            1.01006310e+07, 1.01305740e+07, 1.01430470e+07]]

j=np.array(listj)
j
```

output:

```
array([[ 7602431.,  7660345.,  7790957.,  7860800.,  7909575.,  7943652.,
         8054800.],
       [ 9927600.,  9947800.,  9987000., 10068319., 10100631., 10130574.,
        10143047.]])
```

Now just use slicing (: stands for all, -1 stands for last):

```
print(j[:,-1])
```

Output:

```
 [ 8054800. 10143047.]
```

Comment: I will look over that I apologize  Thank you though for the great explanation